# Footer is not positioned properly on the bottom of the page for different screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When I switch between different resolution screens, the footer gets positioned either upper the bottom line or lower causing scrollbar appear. How could I fix this issue with CSS? I've already tried following several posts, but I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong.

React code:

```
return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <img src={require('../../images/vidn_logo.png')} />
                    </div>
                    {heading}
                    <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
                        <input onChange={this.setEmail} type="email" className="login-form-control"
                            autoComplete="email" placeholder="Email" required></input>
                        <input onChange={this.setPass} type="password" className="login-form-control"
                            autoComplete="new-password" placeholder="Password" required></input>
                        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                            type="submit" style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>Log In</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
```

**Footer component**

```
const Footer = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footerText">
                    <a href="">Privacy</a>All rights reserved<br />
                    <a href=""
                        title="Support Contacts &amp; Procedures">Customer Support</a>
                </div><br />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**.css**:

```
 html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        background: #FBFCFE;
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #2B2B2B;
        height: 100%;
    }
    div {
        display: block;
    }
    .container {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 60px 0 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #footer {
        margin-top: -100px; /* negative value of footer height */
        height: 100px;
        clear:both;
        color: #3f4209;
        text-align: right;
        background: #ccc9c9;
    }
    #footer div#footerText {
        width: 99%;
        padding: 10px 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Why position with `margin-top` in this way as opposed to say `bottom: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple fixed footer (it's hard to tell from your post if you want it fixed to the bottom or not). The main points are `position: fixed`, `bottom: 0` and the padding on the container. If you don't want it fixed, just replace `fixed` with `absolute`

Also, if you can use flexbox there is a [really nice solution here](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/).

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc9c9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```